# Concern about possible electrical shock

Tags: electricity

Very new to all this, however my dumb self touched a live wire, my skin was very dry and it did burn me. The wire was connected to an 18650 battery that says it is "2600mAh 3.7v" I know that even 1 Amp is fatal. However I am not dead, yet. Should I be concerned and visit an ER?

Comment: you got burned because of the temperature of the connector ... a connector can get hot if there is a lot of current flowing in it ... 3.7V would not produce enough current in dry skin

Comment: I see, thank you. I will be mindful next time to not end up in this situation again.

Comment: If an electrical shock is dangerous the effects are pretty much always immediate (heart fibrillation, muscle spasms, etc). There aren't really any long-term negative effects of an electrical shock, with the exception of possible nerve damage.

Comment: Well, internal burns are possible, and their effects might not manifest for a few days, but you still won't get that from a 3.7V battery.

Comment: DerStrom, so there is nothing I should worry about apart from nerve damage?

Comment: i think that you should worry about your lack of knowledge, since you said `I know that even 1 Amp is fatal` .... do some reading

Comment: I'm no doctor but I've never heard of anything. Unless the burn appears to spread over time, I doubt there's an issue, especially (as the others have mentioned) with only 3.7V. I don't think you even got a shock. I said "nerve damage" but I have no evidence that that would ever be an issue. Regardless, keep an eye on it to make sure it doesn't get worse but no, I don't think there's any need to worry about prolonged dangers at this point

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ..... @LukeCallan, please provide a detailed description of what you were doing when you got burned. ... add the description to your question. .... there may be something important that you left out.

Comment: jsotola, what I meant is that I read that one amp could change your heartbeat to the point where it could kill you. But Ill have to read up on that as you noted, thanks for bringing the error to my attention.

Comment: @LukeCallan To be clear, it takes A LOT less than 1 amp to kill you, in fact 5-10 MILLIamps (thousandths of an amp) can kill you in the wrong situation. That being said even if the battery pack is able to source 1A (not talking about mAh at this point - that's an entirely different measurement) there's no guarantee you'll draw that much current from it. Dry skin has a resistance of around 1-2 megohms, IIRC. According to Ohm's Law, the current drawn will be the voltage divided by the resistance. Divide 3.7V by 1 million ohms and you'll see how much current you'd draw even if you did get a shock

Answer (score 4):

3.7V wont pass current through dry skin. As others have mentioned it's MUCH more likely you got a thermal burn.

There is however some danger of getting quite nasty burns when wiring up a battery to a load.

If there are arcs formed during the connection and your fingers are in the same spot, you can get a nasty burn from that 1000C+ spark. These modern batteries pack a lot of punch. Care should always be taken to keep your fingers away from the terminals while wiring these things up.

If your fingers are blistering badly and the skin is broken, a trip to ER to have it properly cleaned and dressed might not be a bad idea.

ADDITION: If you are hooking that battery up to an inductive load, like a motor or a solenoid, there is a high change that breaking the connection will induce a large voltage on the wire. That can give you a bit of a jolt, similar to a static discharge. That is why we use switches.....

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will be more careful next time.

Comment: @LukeCallan see addition.

Comment: I see, so I am not sure whether it was a burn or a shock. But what makes me think it IS a shock is because my hand now feels pretty tired. And this is exactly how it felt when I was shocked by a capacitor once. However, thank you for the response and time.

Comment: @LukeCallan if it was a shock you would feel it in your wrist and in your arm and there would be an involuntary reflex reaction when you touched it. If it gets worse or still feels funny tomorrow get it checked out.

Answer (score 0):

**This battery can't kill you!!!**
The capacity of the battery is 2.6Ah, but that does not mean that your body has run 2.6 A. You can easily calculate how much current has flown through your body by applying Ohms law.

Example:
Realistic bodyresistance Rb=10 kΩ
Vbat=3.7V

Ohm's Law: I=U/R

I=3.7/10000=0.37mA --> you probably can't even feel this amount of current.

What you probably have felt is a shortcircuit between the positiv and negativ terminals of the battery. There is a very low resistance if you short these, so there is a lot of current flowing. If you then touch one of the wires all of the current is flowing through the wires and not through your body, because your body has a lot higher resistance as the wires. The high current throug the wires makes the sparks, the burnmarks on your fingers are from the spark not from the current through your body.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft3jmL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Body resistance varies with voltage, the higher the voltage, the less the impedance of the body is. +48V is considered safe to play with, higher than that it's not suggested. Of course you should not touch hot components either.

Comment: Devil's advocate: The battery *can* kill you!!! If you connect it directly across your heart. Or if you swallow it.